# Can I invoke Servlet without mapping it in web.xml?

Tags: servlets, servlet-mapping

If I have *action* to a *servlet*, we should use **mapping** in XML which is recommended. So it would look like this:

HTML index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

</head><body>
    <form action="go" method="POST">
        Enter name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <button>Submit form :)</button>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

XML mapping:

```
<web-app..........
  
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>ServletOne</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/go</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

Servlet class

```
public class ServletOne extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String s = req.getParameter("name");
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.println("Welcome " + s);

    }
}
```

And it works fine. But my question is what if I don't want to make a mapping - I want to call Servlet class directly. I removed my XML file and I did all of these lines:

```
<form action="ServletOne" method="POST">
<form action="ServletOne.class" method="POST">
<form action="ServletOne.java" method="POST">
```

And.. none of them work. Can I actually call Servlet directly without mapping at all? If yes, how? Sometimes for testing purposes, I don't need to waste time on mapping every servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotation e.g.

```
@WebServlet("/go")
public class ServletOne extends HttpServlet {
    //...
}
```

In fact, Servlet 3.0 onwards, most of the developers prefer this to XML configuration.

Note that the Servlet Specification requires the mapping to start with a `/`. Check [this](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf) to learn more about it.

Comment: You are right sir. Thanks, nice tool. Can I ask what does `/` in `/go` stand by the way? Why can't I simply write `go`?

Comment: @Stefan - It's required by the Servlet Specification. I have added a link to the servlet specification.